# What is a good alternative to SHA1 hashing for password storage?

Tags: php, security, sha1

I have a website which uses SHA1 hashing for passwords. I recently read the following article which argued not to use SHA1 for passwords since SHA1 was never designed to protect passwords: http://arstechnica.com/security/2012/08/passwords-under-assault/4/

Can you please recommend a good hasing method I can implement instead of SHA1 and please provide a link to a tutorial which describes step-by-step how to implement that encryption method using php?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords

Comment: This is addressed in the **faq** tab of PHP questions.

Comment: @Paul: `sha1` is too fast which promotes bruteforce attacks. (Proper) Salting only protects passwords from dictionary/rainbow table attacks.

Comment: Jeff wrote about it once in his blog. It's a [*Good read!*](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/04/speed-hashing.html)

Comment: You want hashing, not encryption.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, SHA1 ain't an encryption algorithm, it is a hashing algorithm.

For password hashing, I advise the use of [PHPass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/). It basically uses the best possible hashing algorithm available on the system your code is installed upon.

> The preferred (most secure) hashing method supported by phpass is the
>   OpenBSD-style Blowfish-based bcrypt, also supported with our public
>   domain crypt_blowfish package (for C applications), and known in PHP
>   as CRYPT_BLOWFISH, with a fallback to BSDI-style extended DES-based
>   hashes, known in PHP as CRYPT_EXT_DES, and a last resort fallback to
>   MD5-based salted and variable iteration count password hashes
>   implemented in phpass itself (also referred to as portable hashes).

Answer (score 1):

`bcrypt` or `scrypt`, however, there is no real implementation of scrypt for php. This article is worth to be read and should give you all information you need: http://www.zimuel.it/en/strong-cryptography-in-php/